# Search skill results different in search skill 'try it' than within Watson Assistant preview link

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I created a watson assistant with two skills. One dialog skill and one search skill. The dialog skill is default, with the 'Anything else' node pointing to the search skill. No customization here in query and filter fields. The search skill is configured within Discovery as web crawl.

I would expect the results within 'try it' and preview link to be the same. But they are different, see the attached print screens.

[image: image: Search skill - try it]

[image: image: Watson Assistant - preview link]

How can I fix this?

Best,
Chris

Comment: Is it this what you hit...? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-search-add#search-skill-add-test

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I understand that it is possible to increase the confidence level threshold. What I don't understand is why the results are different, I would expect that the result of the query is a list of items, ordered by confidence level. So the same in 'try it out' as in the assistant preview link.

Comment: I don't know any details (only a user), but the development team has its own public Slack: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/